# Angular HTML5 mode routing gives he resource cannot be found

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, html

I'm developing an application in .net mvc with angularjs. When I don't use html5 mode it works fine, but when I set html5 mode to true the server calls that address giving me an he resource cannot be found.

This is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/test',
    {
        templateUrl: 'templates/TestPage.html',
        controller: 'ProfesionalController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


});
```

And this is my view (layout):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>


<script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/home/home.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/profesional/profesional.js"></script>
<base href="/">
```

```
         <a href="test">Test</a>
         @*this is the link*@

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="container body-content">
    <div ng-view></div>
    @RenderBody()

</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

When I click to test link the server try to locate:
http://localhost:39881/test" giving me an 404 Not Found - http://localhost:39881/test"

What I'm missing. It works well with no html5 mode.

Comment: did you configure server for html5mode? Have you read the docs for html5mode?

Comment: yes, I read it but I'm not sure what I have to do

Comment: I try using this
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="../index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
but still dosen't work

Comment: shouldn't have a hard time finding the proper config for IIS in a serach. Also use base tag

Comment: You need to configure your server so that it responds with `index.html` to all requests (except static assets like images, css, js files).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, can you provide me some tip of how to do that. I'm really new with routing.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue when I was trying to enable html5 mode in my application. Later when I saw the entire code carefully, I came to know the name of my API call and my route call were same. The browser was getting confused and instead of calling route call it was calling the api call.

Try changing either of the name. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server side rewrites so it doesn't try to load up pages at that path. See details for your server type here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0):

Something that cost me a lot of time that hopefully will help others if you are using Azure and a pure ng app:

I am using Azure and Angular and hit the same problem. I had the IIS Rewrite rules to redirect all requests to the index.html file as per the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) in ng.

However, it still was not working on production, only on local. It turned out to be a stupid user error - my Angular webapp is a pure HTML/JS app (ie. no ASP.NET MVC) and the Azure Publishing Profile had not marked the web.config for dpeloyment to the cloud. I used Kudu on Azure to check the webapp and there was no web.config on live, hence the rewrite rules were not being considered...  changing it to FileType Content solved the issue so the web.config was deployed correctly and the routing now works..